# Get alternative translations from Microsoft Translator API V3

Tags: microsoft-translator

I am using V3 of the Microsoft Translator API with the relative path "/translate". This works fine, but it does provide only one translation for a word and it does not provide any alternative translations.

There is another relative path "/Dictionary/Lookup" which seems to provide translation support and in some cases also additional alternative translations. But for many words it does not provide any translations at all, so maybe it is the wrong approach.

So my question is: What is the offcial and correct way to get additional alternative translations from the Microsoft Translator API (V3)?